# My baby buries her face on the mattress before sleep

Tags: infant, sleep

My 6-month old baby now prefers to sleep on her tummy or her side, but she has some strange behavior prior.

She buries her face on the mattress, moves her buttocks up and down (a bit like a caterpillar) with her face still on the mattress, breathing heavily. After a while, she just turns her head, lays down, sucks on her thumb and goes to sleep.

Is it a known behavior ?

Comment: My nephew used to sleep just like that :P Just trying to get comfortable I guess.

Comment: No reason to worry, I think. My LO does that sometimes. I think that by lying her head she relaxes some muscles in her spine, which in turn allows her to lift her bottom.

Comment: My daughter is going on 18 months and still sleeps on her belly and does the butt wiggle. We started introducing a plush giraffe (agreed to make sure it's baby-safe!) at around 9 mo and then a pillow at 16 mo. 

Of course, she likes wiggling anyway.

Comment: My daughter is going on 18 months and still sleeps on her belly and does the butt wiggle. We started introducing a plush giraffe (agreed to make sure it's baby-safe!) at around 9 mo and then a pillow at 16 mo. Of course, she likes wiggling anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many babies like tactile sensations on their body when going to sleep, I personally think this is why so many children like a stuffed animal in the bed with them. There's nothing wrong with your baby doing that, maybe its a sign that your baby is seeking comforting sensations. A baby-safe stuffed animal (one that has no buttons or pieces that could be pulled off and eaten) in the bed may be just the thing.